# Initialize PostgreSQL-container with command

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, containers

The following Dockerfile is created:

```
 FROM postgres:12

 CMD [«postgres»]
```

And docker-compose.yml

```
 version: '3'
 services:
   codes:
     container_name: short_codes
     build:
        context: codes_store
     image: andrey1981spb/short_codes

     ports:
        - 5432:5432
```

I up docker-compose successfully. But when I try to enter in container, I receive:
"Container ... is not running"

Or I use a wrong command for initializing container.

Comment: `CMD [«postgres»]` looks weird. What do you get from `docker-compose logs codes`?

Comment: In logs I saw, that data-directory in container is not empty. I fixed this, and the problem is solved. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You issue is due to incorrect quotes. Replacing them with proper quotes would solve it:

```
FROM postgres:12

CMD ["postgres"]
```

P.s. Your Dockerfile is essentially identical to the official postgres image, so you might as well use that in your compose yaml, unless you're planning some additional modifications later.

Comment: Yes, your answer is helpful!